# Looping points() with segments() R

Tags: r

I connected points with segments in a Cartesian coordinate system. I stuck by looping the points to the segments, so that I do not have to enter the coordinates for points and segments every time if I want to change them. A for loop would probably help here.

```
x <- -10:10
y <- -10:10

plot(x, y, type = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = FALSE);

axis(1, pos = 0, at = seq(-10, 10, by = 1), las=1, cex.axis=0.5)
axis(2, pos = 0, at = seq(-10, 10, by = 1), las=2, cex.axis=0.5)

points(2,1, col = "blue", pch = 20)
points(5,7, col = "blue", pch = 20)
points(-3,8, col = "green", pch = 20)
points(8,3, col = "green", pch = 20)

segments(2, 1, 5 , 7)
segments(-3, 8, 8, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating the code that plots the points and draws the segments connecting them. In these cases it's better to write a function and call it whenever needed.

Note function argument `pcol`, standing for `point color` and `scol` for the `segment color`.

```
connectPoints <- function(x, y, pcol, pch = 20, scol = "black"){
  points(x[1], x[2], col = pcol, pch = pch)
  points(y[1], y[2], col = pcol, pch = pch)
  segments(x[1], x[2], y[1], y[2], col = scol)
}

plot(x, y, type = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = FALSE);

axis(1, pos = 0, at = seq(-10, 10, by = 1), las=1, cex.axis=0.5)
axis(2, pos = 0, at = seq(-10, 10, by = 1), las=2, cex.axis=0.5)

x1 <- c(2, 1)
y1 <- c(5, 7)
x2 <- c(-3, 8)
y2 <- c(8, 3)

connectPoints(x1, y1, pcol = "blue")
connectPoints(x2, y2, pcol = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know how to fix the tick sizes of the axes? The tick width always adjusts to the plot size. This makes it difficult to spot perpendicular lines.

Comment: @ivo You can set argument **tcl**  `The length of tick marks as a fraction of the height of a line of text. The default value is -0.5`. See `help("par")`.

Comment: @ivo I also added argument `col` in the call to `segments`. It was a `connectPoints` function argument but I forgot to use it in the body of the function.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear with my terminology. I meant that both abscissa and ordinate always have the same unit of length and are congruent to each other. I would like to fix the length even if the plot size is changed. I noticed it is automatically adjusted to the plot size if the aspect ration of the plot is changed. I would like to switch this off.

Comment: @ivo I do not believe that is possible, the tick marks' length is a *fraction* of the height of a line of text, so if the plot is resized so will be the lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function to segment any points you want:

```
myplot<-function(x1=sample(20),y1=sample(20),axis_range=20){
  x <- -axis_range:axis_range
  y <- -axis_range:axis_range

  plot(x, y, type = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = FALSE);

  axis(1, pos = 0, at = seq(-axis_range, axis_range, by = 1), las=1, cex.axis=0.5)
  axis(2, pos = 0, at = seq(-axis_range, axis_range, by = 1), las=2, cex.axis=0.5)
  cols<-sample(colors(),ceiling(length(x1)/2))
  for (i in 1:length(x1)) {
    points(x1[i],y1[i],col = cols[ceiling (i/2)], pch = 20)

  }
  for (j in 1:floor((length(x1)/2))) {
    segments(x1[(2*(j-1))+1],y1[(2*(j-1))+1],x1[2*j],y1[2*j])
  }

}
myplot(x1=sample(20),y1=sample(20),axis_range=20)
```

[image]